# Find sequence of character in word/String and replace with the its occurrence number

Tags: java, string

**Case 1:**

```
String str = "Test something Test";
```

I have to find `Test` and replace with it's occurrence number. Here `Test` appears two time. So the first occurrence shall be replaced with `1` and second occurrence replace with `2`.

Expected output

```
"1 something 2"
```

This is just small string. It may contain more occurrence of `Test` in string/word.

**Case 2:**

```
String str = "TestsomethingTest";
```

Expected output

```
"1something2"
```

I tried with `replace` but it replace all occurrence with same number.

Comment: Run replaceFirst in a loop and increase counter for each time could be a easy but perhaps not very elegant solution

Comment: Use replaceAll with closure. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#replaceAll(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a loop:

```
String str = "Test something Test";

// Look for the first occurence of "Test".
int idx = str.indexOf("Test");

// Counter that will be used as the replacement.
int i = 1;

// While "Test" was found in the string ...
while (idx >= 0) {
    // ... replace it with the current counter value, increase it afterward ...
    str = str.replaceFirst("Test", "" + i++);

    // ... and find the next occurence of "Test".
    idx = str.indexOf("Test");
}

// The result.
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use replaceAll with Closure
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#replaceAll(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

```
def s="abc zde abc"
def i=0

println s.replaceAll("abc"){ ++i }
```